# Getting (500) Internal Server Error with LINE BOT API

Tags: .net, line

I'am doing a simple test of LINE SENDING MESSAGE BOT API, but always getting 500,I even test it on fiddler, still the same situation. [image]here is my main code

Comment: probably related to the `sns.line.models.Content` or `LineContentResponse`, try to print the `message` to see if it is a valid and complete json string.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I used wrong user id.
You can get correct user id from incoming user message:
result[0].content.from instead of result[0].from

https://developers.line.me/bot-api/api-reference#receiving_messages_example